# When would you capitalize "Management", if ever?

Tags: capitalization

I'm editing a technical policy/procedure document, and it says:

> ...does not limit the right of Management to impose additional training....

Is the capitalization correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Comment: I think it would be *very* unusual to capitalise *management* in such contexts. But people quite often do capitalise in, say, [*the right of the State to](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+right+of+the+State+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [do something]*. Again, with no real justification.

Comment: ...anyway, now I've just looked it up. Like I said, capitalisation here [is very unusual](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+right+of+Management+to%2Cthe+right+of+management+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (it basically "flatlines" against the non-capitalised version).

Comment: As mikeY suggests below, legal contracts often capitalize specifically defined terms of art in order to make clear that those terms are being used in their precisely defined sense. If you don't have a specific legal definition of _Management_ spelled out elsewhere in the document, I would advise you not to capitalize the word. Another consideration is balance: If If you adopt the style of capitalizing _Management_, it would seem appropriate to capitalize (and carefully define) _Employees_, as well.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When it is capitalized, it becomes a proper noun, and not one that takes an article, either, as in *It appears that Management have decided you will work overtime without pay.*  It’s the management staff at a specific place, so it is a proper noun.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm certainly not saying it's "incorrect" in any meaningful sense. But on my NGram link there aren't even enough capitalised instances to show on the chart. On [non-case-sensitive Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+right+of+Management+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I get one capitalised instance on the first page, but I gave up looking for a second after half-a-dozen pages. It strikes me as a slightly "facetious" usage - a bit like capitalising the word **Policeman** in a newspaper story (something you'd expect in *The Toytown Gazette*, maybe! :).

Answer (score 7):

Contracts, policy manuals, and rules often use *defined terms*.

See:  http://lexicontools.com/defined_term.php

From that:

> The standard convention in legal documents is to define terms in
>   double quotes and designate subsequent references with initial capital
>   letters.

Management is likely a defined term.  Capitalizing defined terms is common practice in my experience.

EDIT:

Here is an agreement between the University of New Mexico and staff in which Management is a defined and caplitalized term-
http://hr.unm.edu/docs/labor-relations/united-staff-unm-(usunm)-contract.pdf

For fun, here is an agreement in which State is a defined and capitalized term-
http://www.irle.berkeley.edu/library/pdf/0112.pdf

And here is a contract in which the defined terms are in **ALL CAPS** and **BOLD**-
http://www.irle.berkeley.edu/library/pdf/0356.pdf

Comment: To be honest, I think it would actually be rather unlikely for "a technical policy/procedure document" to define the word *management*. They'd likely get seriously bogged down in a quagmire regarding who counts as "management" to who else within the corporate hierarchy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I disagree. Where I work, Management would be a defined term so that its responsibilities and obligations could be reference and discussed.  To me, OP's sentence reads like it is right out of an employment contract or employment policy/procedure document.  The party of the first part would be Management and the party of the second part would be Labor or Union or something like that.  The use of defined terms makes it *easier* to refer to things (instead of bogging them down).

Comment: Well, I don't know what kind of enterprise you work in, or where, but mostly I've worked in UK *office* jobs. Which often have an awful lot of "middle management", and not so much of a "grunt labour force" these days, since we tends to use machines for many jobs that were once done by actual workers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It seems odd you would work in an office, have an interest in language, and not be familiar with defined terms in contracts.  I would guess there are stranger things in the world, however.

Comment: @ Mikey: I did spend almost twenty years running my own business (never with more than half-a-dozen employees, admittedly). But I provided business services to businesses, so I had to be reasonably on the ball about the wording of contracts or I'd have got skinned alive. In the context of a larger organisation, I think it would get *very* tricky trying to define the scope of "Management" (and their associated "rights") as these relate to your burgeoning number of "middle management" employees.

Comment: ...I think you may be thinking of usages such as **The Company** in contracts defining the company's contractual obligations to **customers**. That one is invariably sub-defined as **authorised representatives of [some named organisation]**, but there's no easy way to do that when you're talking about a middle manager who has authority over some workers, but is subservient to others (also what we would often identify as "workers").

Comment: @FumbleFingers  We aren't talking about a specific middle manager. The reference is to Management in a policy document. There are examples online of contractual language where Employer and Company and Management and Union and Employee and other such words are used as defined terms for a particular contract or similar document.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Management as a proper noun ie. as in the management team / the name of a department in a company would be capitalised eg. "have you asked Management about this?" or in a title of a book

However I think the concept of management ie. management of people/ managing people would not be capitalised.

http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_proper_and_common_nouns.htm

Answer (score 1):

It could easily be a matter of style. It's (unfortunately) common for companies to capitalise anything that's Deemed Important.

Is there a house style document you could check?